# How do I setup an asp.net web application on a remote server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, web-applications, razor

Update:
This is the instruction on the server. But following this instruction I cannot find the option "Connect to a site"

[image]

---

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 4 and Razor. Now I have finished my ASP.NET Web Application and I want to upload it to the server and make it accessible to the public.

Previously, I only created websites and upload them to WebCentral (http://www.webcentral.com.au/) by using FX FTP directly and those websites will be accessible immediately.

I have checked that the WebCentral server has the .NET Framework 4.0 version.

Now I want to explore the new advancements in MVC4 and Razor as well as Entity Framework, I chose the ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. After I uploaded this new web application to server, it displays an error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 22:   <system.web>
Line 23:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 24:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 25:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
Line 26:     </authentication>

Source File: \\n5200-2\iis7_www\z\a\zanity.com.au\www\ce\web.config    Line: 24
```

I have no idea about what shall I do to fix this error.
Please help me if you know how to solve this problem.

Thank you very much.

And this is the Web.configure file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVCTry-20120813175505;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If the server has multiple versions of .Net you'll have to go into the properties of the application pool for this website and make sure that it is set to use .Net 4.0 instead of .Net 2.0.

Comment: Joel's suggestion is the first thing I would check, but just because .Net 4.0 is installed doesn't mean that MVC 4 (or any version) is installed on the server.

Comment: @JoelEtherton, I bought a plan on the server, but I don't have the full control about how to configure this server. >_<; Any other ideas?

Comment: @TimMedora, I am just a person who is using other's server to host my web application, so I cannot install MVC 4 on it. Does this mean that all web applications are on the internet so far and not hosted on their own web servers are not a MVC web application?

Comment: You can definitely find MVC hosting...your host may even install it for you if you ask. However, since MVC 4 isn't final yet, you might have to include all the dependencies yourself by copying them to the local bin.

Comment: check [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) and [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I recently found there is an option on the WebCentral Mission Control panel under IIS Management Overview:
1. Select the Web Application folder 
2. Select Settings on the right panel
3. Click Install under Install Application section to install the application on the selected folder.

### By doing this, the selected folder will become a Web Application folder, then I can put the bin and App_Code and App_Data folders under the Web Application folder.

I finally figured it out.

The reason was I didn't put the bin and App_Code folders in the right direction.
On the WebCentral web server, the Web.config file and App_Code folder should be placed under the current project folder, whereas the bin folder should be placed under the /wwwroot folder.

And I copied all dependencies to the bin folder.

This solved all problems.

I'm happy to know that I can run the latest version of ASP.NET MVC 4 as well as Razor on this web server as long as the nedded DLLs are provided in the bin folder.

Cheers :)

Comment: Actually, you should put both App_Code and bin under your project folder. Then you need need to mark your project folder as an application in IIS.

Comment: @jrummell, thank you for your advice, but it's a web server which does not belong to me. I can only upload files to it.

Comment: Most web hosts give you access to IIS tools such as application management. Hopefully your host supports it.

Comment: @jrummell Hi Jru,what you said is exactly what I want. My host supports this configuration, but its instruction is totally incorrect. I'll post the screen shot in my questions, you can have a look and follow it to see whether it works for you or not.